# Downloading new Rigify addon rigify buttons, but none are showing in the tab menu

Tags: rigify

Whenever I download new sets of Rigify buttons, there is nothing showing up in the tab menu to choose new sets.

More precisely: I downloaded a new feature set, which I then tried to add to the Rigify buttons, so I can use those sets for rigging. I downloaded the [Cloudrig](https://gitlab.com/blender/CloudRig) and many others, I installed the zip file within the Rigify add-on in the preferences.

Then when I select the armature and select edit, I go to the Rigify buttons, when I pick say Cloudrig or Gamerig, there are no bones. I believe either I'm on an old version of Blender or that the feature set is broken.

Comment: It sometimes shows an error down below like, Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: What Rigify buttons? Blender's built-in Rigify addon doesn't have downloadable buttons to my knowledge.

Comment: By "new rigify buttons" do you mean a "feature set"? - like the [CloudRig](https://gitlab.com/blender/CloudRig)? - Also, it would help to know what you actually download from where, and how you tried to install it.

Comment: Im sorry, I'm just complicating my words. I downloaded a new feature set, which I then tried to add to the rigify buttons, so I can use those sets for rigging. I downloaded the cloudrig and many others, I instal the zip file within the rigify add on in preferences. Then when I select the armature and select edit, i go to the rigify buttons, when I pick say cloudrig or gamerig, there are no bones. I believe either Im on an old version of blender or that the feature set is broken :(

Comment: Don't worry, I just want to make sure we're talking about the same thing. I've edited your question to make it more clear. So you installed feature sets but their UI buttons for the bone layers and properties are missing in the viewport's side panel (the "N-panel"), right? Cloud Rig is available for Blender 2.8x, 2.9x, and 3.x. If you picked the right version it should work.

Comment: Two more questions: 1) Have you pressed the *Generate Rig* button? The buttons in the N-panel are created by a script. It's *cloudrig.py* for the CloudRig and it's run by this button. But you can run it manually. 2) Have you used a base rig (*Add > Armature > Cloud Humans > ...*) or have you used your own armature and then assigned a *Rigify Type* to the bone?

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, thats correct, they are missing for some odd reason. I'm using blender 2.X because my computer cannot handle higher updates and as you mentioned, the version 2.83 should work then. I have not pressed the generate rig option, because there are set of rigify buttons I wanna use for the rig build up. I used the meta rig human from the rigify. So everything is rigify based sort of say.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, there is bad news. Quote from the CloudRig github site: *"It is currently recommended not to mix CloudRig and Rigify elements."*. So better use either pure CloudRig elements or just Rigify elements. Maybe you can find an equivalent element. The *CloudRig* tab will appear when you press Generate Rig button the first time. When you save the file, restart Blender and open the file again, the script tries to run automatically to add the buttons for the side panel. For security reasons, you will receive a prompt where you must allow the script to run.

Comment: Thanks Blunder for the help! I'll try this out and thanks for helping me out again. I'll let you know if something unusual is happening :)